# How do I get rid of this warning in my Spring Bean Configuration file in SpringSource ToolSuite (Eclipse)

Tags: spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-integration

I have the following small file to reproduce the warning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd">

    <int:service-activator input-channel="stageEventChannel"
        ref="stageScoreUpdateService" method="receiveEvent" />

</beans>
```

This produces the warning, "Referenced bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0' not found".  The "stageEventChannel" and "stageScoreUpdateService" should not be the cause of the warning, since I can reproduce it with different channels and different services in my system.  In any case, the warning seems to be referring to the ServiceActivatorFactoryBean, which is not what I'm implementing.

I am using SpringSource Tool Suite 2.8.0.RELEASE.

I've searched on the forums and only found [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?109075-Referenced-bean-ServiceActivatorFactoryBean-0-not-found) of a person having a very similar issue but no responses.

Comment: DO you have spring-integration-core jar on your classpath?

Comment: Yes, spring-integration-core-2.0.3.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Spring Integration 2.0.6+

See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-2295

Comment: Thanks, I logged that issue, actually.  2.0.6 is not released, yet.  I don't know what the schedule is.